# Getting fs.readFileSync is not a function in Ionic3-angular5 app

Tags: ionic3, angular5, pdf-reader

The scenario is, user will choose a .pdf file and we extract data from the PDF. We are using ionic3 with angular 5.

In HTML, we write

```html
<ion-input type="file" accept="pdf/*" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">
<button ion-button large block type="submit" (click)="UploadCertificate()">Get Data</button>
```

In the .ts file,

```js
declare var require: any;
fileToUpload: File;

changeListener(files: FileList): void {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
  }

UploadCertificate() {
    var pdfReader = require("pdfreader");
    new pdfReader.PdfReader().parseFileItems(this.fileToUpload.name, function (err, item) {
      if (item && item.text)
        console.log(item.text);
    });
  }
```

We are getting a error like,  fs.readFileSync is not a function. we are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader.
Please suggest.

Comment: the `pdfreader` package is for serverside code, where it can read the file from the disk (via `fs.readFileSync`) Your code is running on the clientside in a browser, which has no direct access to the filesystem, thus cannot use **node's** `fs` module ... It's also written in the very beginning of the package description *"This module is meant to be run using Node.js only. It does not work from a web browser."*  Furthermore, citing the package's docs, it's based on [`pdf.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/), which is available in the browser. Maybe you can use that ...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will Pdf.js run in cordova?